# how to display treeview in php

Tags: php, jquery

CAn anyone tell me is it is possible to display the files in computer using a tree view in php? It should be fast enough to display either in jQuery or anyother method that gives speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort them by type (category/file) by looping them in a format that works with a CSS:ed threaded view, e.g.: http://cssglobe.com/post.asp?id=903